# Real Analysis: Prove using the definition of being continuous on a multi-variable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

Prove using the definition that the function is continuous on f(x,y) = |x-y|

How would one go about proving this with the definition of continuity? I don't know where to start in terms of picking a δ or ε. 
Also the fact that it's in absolute values confuses me.

Can anyone help me or point me into the right direction of where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^{2}$ and $\epsilon  >0$. Then $$|f(x,y)-f(a,b)| =|(x-y)-(a-b)|=|(x-a)-(y-b)|  \leq |x-a| +|y-b|$$ $$ \leq 2\sqrt {(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}}<\epsilon $$ if $\sqrt {(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}}< \frac {\epsilon} 2$, so take $\delta =\frac {\epsilon} 2$.